# Get image size after resize JavaScript

Tags: javascript, image, resize

I am trying to resize an image based off of a max-width/max-height array. Here's what I've come up with so far:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Image resize test</title>
    <script>
        function createImage(){
            //The max-width/max-height
            var maxDim = [500,500];
            //Create the image
            var img = document.createElement("img");
            img.setAttribute("src","http://nyrixcorp.com/images/eggplant_service.png");
            document.body.appendChild(img);
            //Function for resizing an image
            function resize(){
                //resize the image
                var portrait = this.width < this.height;
                this[portrait ? "height" : "width"] = maxDim[portrait ? 1 : 0];
                //What is the height? PROBLEM HERE!!!
                console.log(this.height);
            }
            //Is the image loaded already?
            var temp = new Image();
            temp.src = img.src;
            var loaded = typeof temp.complete != "undefined" ? temp.complete : !isNaN(temp.width+temp.height) && temp.width+temp.height != 0;
            //Fire the resize function
            if (loaded) resize.call(img);
            else img.addEventListener("load",resize,false);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="createImage()">
</body>
</html>
```

You should be able to run this file as-is. It is able to get the width/height after loading the image. But once you alter the width, it still logs the old height. The only browser that works correctly appears to be Firefox (newer versions). All the other browsers don't update the height attribute until the window is finished loading.

Does anyone know a fix for this? The image is already loaded, but it isn't giving the correct resized dimensions.

Comment: works fine on chrome 14.0.835.187m

Comment: I'm using chrome 13, and it works the first time the page loads. When you refresh, however, it gives the wrong height.

Comment: @Azmisov how is it changing the height to 160 in case of FF and chrome didnt see anything written for that in your code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't change the `height` yet, because your image's height > width, make `portrait = false`;

When you change the width, in IE8, it will only resize the width, but in chrome it will both change the width and height, I think this is browser depended.

You can fix this by both change the height and with manually.

Comment: I had thought leaving off the height attribute would let the image resize proportionally. Would you know if setting max-width/max-height styles would resize the image proportionally in IE7+? Sorry, I don't presently have IE installed on my machine.

Comment: @Azmisov I test on IE8, with css style max-width, it doesn't work at all, even when I fix it with `width:auto;max-width:10px;`

Comment: Okay, this seems like the only cross-browser possibility.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting width/height you can try to set image.style.maxWidth/image.style.maxHeight then image will resize with preserving aspect ratio.

Comment: Do you know if this works in IE7, Safari 4, Chrome 12, FF 3.6, and Opera 10.6?

Comment: For IE7 max-width/max-height css styles does not work. For other browsers should be fine. If IE < 8 support is important, than I recommend to calculate ratio and update width and height both accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

IE doesnt recognize addEvenetListener and you must handle it your self based on brower.. possible solution

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Image resize test</title>
    <script>
        function createImage(){
            //The max-width/max-height
            var maxDim = [500,500];
            //Create the image
            var img = document.createElement("img");
            img.setAttribute("src","http://nyrixcorp.com/images/eggplant_service.png");
            document.body.appendChild(img);
            //Function for resizing an image
            function resize(){
                //resize the image
                var portrait = this.width < this.height;
                this[portrait ? "height" : "width"] = maxDim[portrait ? 1 : 0];
                //What is the height? PROBLEM HERE!!!
                console.log(this.height);
            }
            //Is the image loaded already?
            var temp = new Image();
            temp.src = img.src;
            var loaded = typeof temp.complete != "undefined" ? temp.complete : !isNaN(temp.width+temp.height) && temp.width+temp.height != 0;
            //Fire the resize function
            if (loaded) resize.call(img);
            else{ 
            if(isIE == true) // check here for browser 
            img.onload = resize;
            else
            img.addEventListener("load",resize,false);}
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="createImage()">
</body>
</html>
```

it will work fine just u need to pass `true` or `false` to `isIE` based on the browser you are using

Comment: Better way:
if (img.addEventListener) {
  ...
} else if (img.attachEvent) {
  ...
} else {
  img.onload = ...
}