# Get actual image size, after resizing it

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a page filled with thumbnails, resized with css to `150x150`, and when I click on a thumbnail, the page dims, and The image is being shown in it's true sizes.

Currently, I have to manually create an array that includes the actual height of all images. For solving a design issue+less manual operation of my gallery, I need to get the actual height of an image, after I resized it (CSS).

I tried:

```
var imageheight = document.getElementById(imageid).height;
```

And:

```
var imageheight = $('#' + imageid).height();
```

But both return the `150px` attribute assigned with the CSS. How can I solve this? Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7682772/get-image-size-after-resize-javascript

Comment: So you are loading all the full size images instead of making proper thumbnails? Ouch...

Comment: I'm loading the full size image, and showing it when a thumbnail is being clicked.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

One way you could do it is create a separate image object.

```
function getImageDimensions(path,callback){
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function(){
        callback({
            width : img.width,
            height : img.height
        });
    }
    img.src = path;
}

getImageDimensions('image_src',function(data){
    var img = data;

    //img.width
    //img.height

});
```

That way, you'll use the same image but not the one on the DOM, which has modified dimensions. Cached images, as far as i know, will be recycled using this method. So no worries about additional HTTP requests.

Answer (score 29):

you have the 'natural' kws to help you out:

with js:

```
var imageheight = document.getElementById(imageid).naturalHeight;
```

or with jquery

```
var imageheight = $('#' + imageid).naturalHeight;
```

Comment: for IE9+ and any other major browser, these properties are valid. This is a good answer! Someone probably wrapped a jQuery plugin for this. If not, this might be interesting to have.

Answer (score 2):

@Dinesh's answer to just use the `naturalHeight` and `naturalWidth` property is great and probably should be the accepted answer.

Just wanted to add two things here that could save people hours since I see many SO posts around this issue and have myself spent quite sometime on it.

1. **`naturalHeight` may return `0` or `undefined` if called before the image is loaded**. Just setting `src` attribute may not mean that the image is loaded immediately. I have seen that it is best to fetch it in `onload`.

   ```
   $('selector')[0].onload = function() {
     alert(this.naturalHeight);
     alert(this.naturalWidth);
   }
   ```
2. If not using `this`, just **`$('selector').naturalHeight` may not work**. You may need to access the associated DOM element i.e `$('selector')[0].naturalHeight` or `$('selector').get(0).naturalHeight` since we are using native Javascript's attribute `naturalHeight`. See [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23467709/1526703) for more details.

Comment: I spent hours wondering why `naturalWidth` returned `undefined`, now I know why (+1).